# Where can one find the open source Python implementation of `cv2.warpAffine`?

Tags: python, opencv

Where is the python implementation of modules of OpenCV, like `https://github.com/opencv/opencv`, for example for `cv2.warpAffine`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Python implementation.

The Python API of OpenCV calls into compiled library code that was written in C++.

OpenCV is highly optimized, containing multiple optimized code paths for various functions. It's a challenge to find the code that is actually executed. Some of it is ***OpenCL***.

`warpAffine` will be found in the `imgproc` module, in one of the `imgwarp` source files.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e9f35610a54479eb170c101745cbd6bcc8e1d122/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L2726